# How to start webcam detection with Detectron2 on Google Colab?

Tags: segmentation-fault, google-colaboratory, webcam, detection, detectron

I'm using Detectron2 to implement real time segmentation. After training my model, I tried to perform the inference on my webcam video, using this script:

`!git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2`

`%run detectron2/demo/demo.py --config-file /content/config.yml --webcam --confidence-threshold 0.6 --opts MODEL.WEIGHTS /content/output/model_final.pth`

The output was:

```
[06/15 12:33:39 detectron2]: Arguments: Namespace(confidence_threshold=0.6, config_file='/content/config.yml', input=None, opts=['MODEL.WEIGHTS', '/content/output/model_final.pth'], output=None, video_input=None, webcam=True)
[06/15 12:33:40 fvcore.common.checkpoint]: [Checkpointer] Loading from /content/output/model_final.pth ...
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
```

However, the webcam does not work.

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yuxin Wu (The creator of detectron2) commented [on this github issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/1193) that this is more of a placeholder feature for people to build code off of, and the "--webcam" input does not save outputs:

> Working as expected as `--webcam` does not currently save outputs.
> You can take the script as an example to implement new functionalities.